# Extracting and sorting data from a binary file

Tags: python, sorting, math, binary, sequences

So I just started a programming course in python and I have this assignment called 'Wind data analysis' in which I am to extract data from a bin.file and sort it into  x,y and z values. So far I got:

```
filename="turb21351_L72u.bin"
with open(filename,'br') as f: 

buffer = f.read(100000)
print("Length of buffer is %d" % len(buffer))

for i in buffer:
    print(int(i))
```

Which works fine (note; there are some indentation error on the script i wrote here) and gives me value in the range 1 to 300.

The problem is sorting the data. The description of the assignment sounds like this:

"The data file consists of Nz X Ny X Nx numbers (floating point single precision). The sequence of the numbers corresponds to indexes
z, y and x which all increase sequentially from 1 to Nz, Ny and Nx respectively. The fastest-varying index is z, followed by y, and the slowest varying index is x. That is,
the first Nz numbers from the sequence correspond to indexes z going from 1 to Nz, y = 1, and x = 1. Based on this ordering rule, the function must convert the data to a three-dimensional array with dimensions Nz X Ny X Nx."

My question is:

How is the assigniment description to be understood mathmathtically and how would one go about sorting it based on the ordering rule?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with the following code:

```
filename="turb21351_L72u.bin"
with open(filename,'br') as f:
    buffer = f.read(100000)
print("Length of buffer is %d" % len(buffer))

for i in buffer:
    print(int(i))
```

In python the `with` keyword is used when working with unmanaged resources (like file streams). The `with` statement works like a block statement, where it needs indentation.

From [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement):

> The `with` statement clarifies code that previously would use `try...finally` blocks to ensure that clean-up code is executed. In this section, I’ll discuss the statement as it will commonly be used. In the next section, I’ll examine the implementation details and show how to write objects for use with this statement.
>
> The `with` statement is a control-flow structure whose basic structure is:
>
> ```
> with expression [as variable]:
>     with-block
> ```
>
> The expression is evaluated, and it should result in an object that supports the context management protocol (that is, has `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods).

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it just gives me a long sequence of numbers. Im interested in receiving an array of numbers.